# C++ Having Windows Service Start another Program

Tags: c++, service, process

Is it possible to create a windows service to create and maintain another process? Like I'm writing a program, and say a virus killed the process, could I have my window service running and basically 'watching' it? I already have the code for a regular application that stays running and executes a program if it's not currently running, to keep it running.

I've never written a service before, but would it be that hard to just write this simple program, which basically runs a check to see if the process is running, if not, it executes it and sleeps for a few minutes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible.  It is not uncommon to see third-party apps have watchdog services to keep them running in case of crashes.  A service can enumerate running processes using `EnumProcesses()`, and if the desired executable is not running then start a new copy of it using `CreateProcessAsUser()`.

If the service is the one starting the executable process in the first place, or can find it after an enumeration, one optimization would be to keep an open handle to the process (returned by `CreateProcess...()`, or use `OpenProcess()` on the process ID an enumeration returns), and then use a wait function, like `WaitForSingleObject()`, to detect when the process stops running.  That way, you don't have to enumerate processes to find out if the intended process is still running or not.

Comment: I'm sure Ive installed a service before but I cannot remember, is it the same as executing an .exe file? Like, I want to be able to have my program be executed and have both the program and the service executed with just the double-click of the exe. Possible?

Comment: Running a service is not the same as running an application. Although a service is usually (but does not need to be) an .exe file, it must be installed into, and run by, the Service Control Manager. There is a `CreateService()` function for installing a service programmably, and a `StartService()` function for starting a service programmably. So yes, it is possible to have your main app start the service if it is not already running, and then the app could use an IPC mechanism to pass its current process handle to the service so it knows which process to track without enumerating to find it.

Comment: The app could then stop the service using `ControlService()` if it is being closed normally, and the service can restart the app (and get the new handle to it) using `CreateProcessAsUser()` if the app closes unexpectedly.

Comment: Thanks, and instead of starting a new thread I figure I'll ask: Since its possible to pack 2 exe's together, is it possible with a service + an exe, so I wouldn't have to have 2 .exes, just one?

Comment: A service runs in its own process. You could have a single .exe file, as long as it knows which mode it is running in. For example, when the .exe file is installed into the SCM, you could include a `/service` command-line parameter when the SCM runs the .exe file. That way, when the .exe is run, it can look to see if that parameter was specified, and if so then perform service-related operations, otherwise perform app-related operations instead.

Comment: It is certainly doable, my company's own software runs in both service and app modes, but we utilize a 3rd party framework to manage that for us, but it would not be too much work to implement the necessary API calls manually.

Comment: Well I was thinking of going the route of just using a standard packer and bind the programs together. The thing is, I can't hve them switch modes, I literally need a service helper and this program that will be a running process. I'm making the service now currently .